# Foucault's pendulum; ball bearing?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, experimental-physics, string

Is is a ball bearing necessary to prevent the cord from twisting in a Foucault pendulum?

Comment: Well, probably not twisting but affecting the direction of the swing mostly.

Comment: if the swing pendulum was hanging from a hinge mounted on the bottom of a table with wheels that could slowly and freely turn, that might substitute well for a ball bearing.